# Inverting order of checks in insertion sort leds to SegFault

Tags: c, sorting, pointers

What I am trying to do is sort the columns of a matrix using the insertion_sort algorithm, this is the sorting function that goes into segfault, I tried troubleshooting and found out that setting `j>=0` to `j>0` makes the code run well, however the first element doesn't get sorted.

```
void insertion_sort(int ***A, int n, int m) {
    int key, j;

    for (int k = 0; k < m; k++)
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        key = *A[i][k];
        
        for(j = i - 1; key > *A[j][k] && j >= 0; j--) {
            *A[j + 1][k] = *A[j][k];
        }

        *A[j + 1][k] = key;
  }
}
```

Just in case I made some mistake in allocating memory, I am leaving the function to allocate memory here too:

```
int*** allocMatrix(int n, int m) {
    int ***a = calloc(n, sizeof(int**));
    
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = calloc(m, sizeof(int*));

        for(j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            a[i][j] = calloc(1, sizeof(int));
            *a[i][j] = i + j;
        }
    }

    return a;
}
```

The exercise I am trying to solve requires you to make a pointer matrix, that is why I am not using an `int**` instead.

Comment: `*key = *A[i][k];` key isn't a pointer. Does this even compile cleanly ?

Comment: @John3136 edited, moments ago I tried using a pointer instead to no avail, I forgot to completely revert the change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was indeed in the sorting function, I tought the for conditions were executed at the same time but i was wrong, inverting `key > *A[j][k] && j >= 0` to `j >= 0 && key > *A[j][k]` fixed the issue.

At some point in the cycle j became `j = -1` and as the first instruction is evaluated it tried to access `A[-1][k]` which led to the segfault.